# ASP.Net MVC only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a model classes defined as

```
public partial class RoadSegCond
{

    public int ThanaID { get; set; }
    public short RoadID { get; set; }
    public int FromChain { get; set; }
    public virtual SurfaceType SurfaceType { get; set; } 
}

public partial class SurfaceType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class SegmentWiseConditionViewModel
{
    public int ThanaID { get; set; }
    public short RoadID { get; set; }
    public int FromChain { get; set; }      
    public string surfaceType { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I want to send the information to a View model but it shows the
Error **The specified type member 'SurfaceType' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.**

My controller is

```
 public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
 {
        var model = from r in new RSDMSEntities().RoadSegConds
                    select new SegmentWiseConditionViewModel
                    {
                        RoadID = r.RoadID,
                        ThanaID = r.ThanaID,
                        FromChain = r.FromChain,
                        SurfaceType = r.SurfaceType.Name,
                    };


        DataSourceResult result = model.ToDataSourceResult(request);

        return Json(result);

 }
```

the viewmodel

```
 public class SegmentWiseConditionViewModel
{
    public int ThanaID { get; set; }
    public short RoadID { get; set; }
    public int FromChain { get; set; }
    public string surfaceType { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You have not shown your `SegmentWiseConditionViewModel` model.

Comment: And you `RoadSegCond` does not have a navigation property (e.g. `int `SurfaceTypeID`)

Comment: public class SegmentWiseConditionViewModel
    {
        public int ThanaID { get; set; }
        public short RoadID { get; set; }
        public int FromChain { get; set; }
        public string surfaceType { get; set; }

    }

Comment: Edit your question with the relevant code (not in comments). But the issue if that `RoadSegCond` does not have a navigation property for `SurfaceType` (see my second comment)

Comment: thx, now see the question.